# Arithmetic Progression and Geometric Progression

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

The $1$-st, $3$-rd and $9$-th term of an A.P is are the first three terms of a G.P. If the $7$-th term of an A.P is $14$ then calculate:
i.$12$-th term of A.P
ii. Sum of the first $12$-th term of G.P.

Comment: Could you post what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Arithmetic progression can be modelled as
$$a_n=a_0+nd$$
and geometric progression as
$$b_n=b_0q^n.$$
We know this:
$$b_0=a_0$$
$$b_1=a_2=a_0+2d=b_0q$$
$$b_2=a_8=a_0+8d=b_0q^2$$
$$a_6=a_0+6d=14$$
There are four equations and four unknown variables, so you can easily solve it and obtain:
$$(a_0,b_0,d,q)=(14,14,0,1)$$
or
$$(a_0,b_0,d,q)=(2,2,2,3).$$
Now you can easily get the answers

I) $14$ or $24$

II) $168$ or $531440$

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_1=a$.

Hence,

$$(a+2d)^2=a(a+8d),$$ which gives $d^2=ad$.

1. $d=0$.

Hence, since $a_7=14$, we obtain $a=14$ and $S_{12}=12\cdot14=168$ and $a_{12}=14$;

2. $d=a$.

In  this case $d+6d=14$, which gives $a=d=2$.

Thus,
$$a_{12}=2+11\cdot2=24$$ and $q=\frac{6}{2}=3.$

Thus, 
$$S_{12}=\frac{2(3^{12}-1)}{3-1}=3^{12}-1.$$

Comment: pls can u expantiate

Comment: @FERANMI ABIONA Yes, of course! What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

We have

$$a_3=a_1+2r=a_1q$$
$$a_9=a_1+8r=a_1q^2$$
$$a_7=a_1+6r=14$$

thus
$$(a_1+2r)^2=a_1 (a_1+8r) $$
or
$$4a_1r+4r^2=8a_1r $$
hence

$$r=a_1=2 \; ,\;q=3$$

thus

> $$a_{12}=a_1+11r=24$$

the sequences are
$$2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20... $$

$$2,6,18,.... $$

for the second question, the sum is

> $$S=2 (1+3+3^2+...3^{11})=3^{12}-1$$

Comment: This is missing the trivial case $(a_1,b_1,r,q)=(14,14,0,1)$.

Comment: @dromastyx Yes but i look for non trivial sequences.